# What would be the best way to locate this element using Xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, xpath

We have the following DOM structure:

```
/button
/button
/button
/button
/button
```

We need to locate an element using Xpath, but the trick is, **we cannot use indexes in our Xpath or we cannot even store the elements in a list and then access them by using indexes.**
This was an interview question that I was asked, so I don't have more information and I could not answer this question.
What would be the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Do they have any property? class, type, style, or something like this.

Comment: @j.barrio, nope, we do not have any other properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in xpath

```
//button[1] //first button...and so on
//button[2]
```

or
xpath has lots of functions to locate like

1. last()
2. position()

so you can use this function like

```
//button[last()-1]
```

or

```
//button[position()=2]
```

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: No Amruta, we cannot, like I said in the question description, I am not allowed to use indexes. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Hey Amruta, Thanks for the update, this one sounds good, thanks a lot. I'll search the web for more Xpath functions and practice it too.

Comment: Amruta, can you also do us another favour, by sharing the link to some sources where we could refer these Xpath functions?

Comment: References added to my answer if it is helpful please accept my answer and help community.